# Something wrong with my LINQ to Entities query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I currently have a LINQ query:

```
public List<EventSchool> GetEventSchools(int eventID)
    {
        var eventSchools = db.EventSchools
            .Include("Organisation")
            .Where(e => e.EventID == eventID)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var ev in eventSchools)
        {
            if (db.EventSchoolKeyStages.Where(e => e.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID).Count() > 0)
            {
                int ks = db.EventSchoolKeyStages
                .Where(e => ev.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID)
                .Sum(e => e.Males + e.Females);

                ev.StudentNumbers = ks;
            }
        }

        return eventSchools;
    }
```

When I inspect EventSchools, the student numbers for ALL items in the list shows as the first total.

For example, if I have 3 items in the list:

```
Item 1 - Males = 10, Females = 10
Item 2 - Males = 1, Females = 2
Item 3 - Males = 200, Females = 500
```

ALL items have a StudentNumbers of 20, rather than:

```
Item 1 - 20
Item 2 - 3
Item 3 - 700
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
.Where(e => ev.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID)
```

This lambda will always be true. I suspect you meant

```
.Where(e => e.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID)
            ^^^
```

which is different in the indicated place.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your query:

```
.Where(e => ev.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID)
```

Should be:

.`Where(e => e.EventSchoolID == ev.EventSchoolID)`